# Facing issue in connecting polkadot UI with nodes running on gcp [updated]

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, validator, nodes

I'm running 3 validator nodes on different vm instances on gcp but I'm not able to connect these node with the polkadot UI.

Here are the commands which I'm using to run the nodes:

```
./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/bob --chain local --bob --port 30335 --rpc-port 9944 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator -lruntime=debug --rpc-methods Unsafe   --name bob   --bootnodes /ip4/external-ip/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
```

```
./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/alice --chain local --alice --port 30333 --rpc-port 9945 --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator -lruntime=debug
```

```
./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/charlie --chain local --charlie --port 30334 --rpc-port 9945 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator -lruntime=debug --bootnodes /ip4/external-ip/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
```

I tried to run this command on instances to get port info:

```
deepak$ netstat -tuln | grep 9944
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9944          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

On polkadot UI, I'm putting this as a endpoint: `wss://external-ip:9945`

After adding `--unsafe-rpc-external`

I'm not still facing the same issue on polkadot UI. Here are logs which happens when UI tries to connect:

```
2024-02-23 07:07:46.958  INFO tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: Accepting new connection 1/100
2024-02-23 07:07:46.958  WARN tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2024-02-23 07:07:47.514  INFO tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: Accepting new connection 1/100
2024-02-23 07:07:47.514  WARN tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::server: HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2024-02-23 07:07:48.538  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (2 peers), best: #675 (0x2144…a767), finalized #673 (0x6018…0a29), ⬇ 2.1kiB/s ⬆ 1.8kiB/s
```

How can i solve this issue?

Just FYI: websocket is not secured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the flag `--unsafe-rpc-external` to listen in all interfaces, since currently the rpc is only *listening* on `localhost` so can't be connected from outside (or you need a proxy in front to listen connections and route to the node/s).

```
      --unsafe-rpc-external
          Listen to all RPC interfaces.
```

---

*Update*: With this the instance is ready to accepting connection over the `extenal-ip` **but** using polkadotjs apps will not works since the browser restrictions of open a `ws` connection from a secure sire (https). To workaround this you can create a reverse tunnel with `ssh` and use localhost to connect to your instance. The tunnel can be created with this command

```
ssh -g -L 9945:localhost: 9945 -f -N user@gcp-intance
```

And then you can use `ws://localhost:9945`

Thx!

Comment: Yeah, Now I'm able to see this: `'$ netstat -tuln | grep 9944
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9944            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN '` But on polkadot UI connection is not successful, getting this - `Waiting to establish a connection with the remote endpoint.`

Comment: You may need to allow ingress traffic to those ports in GCP, since ingress could be disable by default.

Comment: Checked! all the ports are open.still facing the same issue. Updated the question with logs which get generated when UI tries to connect.

Comment: By UI you mean `https://polkadot.js.org`? Also, the ws connection should be something like `ws://external-ip:9945`. You can also trying adding  the flag `--rpc-cors all` to allow all origins

Comment: If I use `ws://external-ip:9945` then I got: `Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`. But when I try to setup a unsecure connection from WebSocket Tester then it got connected

Comment: That because the browser have a security restriction, there are a few ways to resolve this like create a tunnel that allow to use localhost to initialize the ws connection. For example with 
`ssh -g -L 9945:localhost: 9945 -f -N user@gcp-intance` and then you can just use ws://localhost:9945 to connect.

Comment: yeah that's working now! thank you so much for your time

Comment: awesome, I will update the answer to add this info.